# Wordpress: Filter by Time not loading

Tags: wordpress

I am having an issue in wordpress where I cannot filter by time properly.

I have 4 options, which are as follows:
1) Any Time
2) Today
3) This Week
4) This Month

The issue with this is all the options work, except for the today option. I will post the code below for your reference. Any help will be much appreciated.

**NOTE: The theme being used is EventBuilder. And I cannot access their support system**

**CODE:**

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <select id="listingFormTime" name="listingFormTime">

            <option value="" <?php selected( $time, "" ); ?>><?php _e( "Any Time", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
            <option value="1" <?php selected( $time, 1 ); ?>><?php _e( "Today", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
            <option value="2" <?php selected( $time, 2 ); ?>><?php _e( "This Week", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>
            <option value="3" <?php selected( $time, 3 ); ?>><?php _e( "This Month", "themesdojo" ); ?></option>

        </select>

    </div>
```

I think this filter is in AJAX I am not very sure, Have been given this code by somebody and having a lot of issues fixing them. Kindly get back to me on any queries or anything else that is required. Thank You.

**EDIT: With the surrounding code**

```
    jQuery(document).on('click','#reset-filter', function(e) {

            jQuery('#my_listings_current_page').val('1');
            jQuery('#filterKeywords').val('');
            jQuery('#filterLocation').val('');
            jQuery('#listingFormLoc').val('');
            jQuery('#listingFormCat').val('');
            jQuery('#listingFormTime').val('');
            jQuery('#latitude').val('');
            jQuery('#longitude').val('');
            jQuery('.tag-filter').removeClass('active');
            jQuery('#filter-tags-holder input').remove();
            jQuery( "#advance-search-slider" ).css("display", "none");

            $.fn.tdSubmitFilterMap();

            $.fn.tdSubmitFilter();

            $.fn.tdSubmitFilterList();

            e.preventDefault();

        });
```

Comment: We can't see what's wrong with this code. We need the PHP code... look for "listingFormTime" in functions.php maybe...

Comment: Sorry, I could not find the name in functions.php

Comment: So can you look into the whole "wp-content" folder then ?

Comment: Still nothing, it's just not working on selecting today, It works with the other 3 options.

Comment: yeah, but for this, we need to see the code using this "select"... that's strange you don't find "listingFormTime", since it should be at least in the code you wrote here...

Comment: `jQuery('#listingFormTime').val('');` if this will help? But all that does is reset the value.

Comment: So, what is the code around the jQuery line ? you may edit your question to add this code.

Comment: Can I come on Chat now?

Comment: Can you show your live site?

Comment: [www.ticketpapa.com](http://www.ticketpapa.com)

Comment: It's hard to understand how it works... on the submit button, it makes an POST ajax call to `http://www.ticketpapa.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. Do you have anything in you admin-ajax.php that seems to use `listingFormTime` or `td-filter-listings`. There should be an unserialize on the POST content...